# How select a specific file from a listview

Tags: java, android, file, listview, button

I have made an Android app in which you can load a set of files that are in a folder to an external storage via a "ListView" Java. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    private ListView mainListView ;  
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );  
        ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();  

        File storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(storage,"/myfolder/");
        if (file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
            for (String s : file.list()) {
                sb.append(s + " ");
                List.addAll( Arrays.asList(s) );
            }
        }

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.rowTextView,List); 
        mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );  
    }
```

I added a botton "Open" near every loaded file in the "simplerow.xml":

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Open" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>
```

I added this button because I want to open the selected file with the click of button.
How can I do it? How can I select the specific file? How can I retrieve the path of the selected file?

Comment: You'll implement `Custom Array Adapter` for that...

Comment: you can go through this link -http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9

Answer (score 1):

Add Click Listener for your listview like:

```
mainListView .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            File myFile = new File(List.get(position));
            FileOpen.openFile(mContext, myFile);
    }

});

public class FileOpen {

    public static void openFile(Context context, File url) throws IOException {
        // Create URI
        File file=url;
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        // Check what kind of file you are trying to open, by comparing the url with extensions.
        // When the if condition is matched, plugin sets the correct intent (mime) type, 
        // so Android knew what application to use to open the file
        if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
            // Word document
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
            // PDF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
            // Powerpoint file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
            // Excel file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
            // RTF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
            // GIF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
            // JPG file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
            // Text file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
        } else if(url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
            // Video files
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
        } else {
            //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file

            //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
            //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
            //so you can choose which application to use
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        }

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And you also have to store the file path somewhere so that you easily pass the selected file path onItemClickListener

Comment: but how do I find the path of the selected file?

Answer (score 0):

use [setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29) method of ListView

This would register the ItemSelectedListener and then open the selected item in ItemSelectedListener.